# Recommendations for email hosting

Tags: untagged

We're considering outsourcing the email service for our domain so that we can avoid the headaches of email delivery and getting the mail through spam filters. We don't send any bulk mail, just for email address confirmation (when users register) and for new message notifications (when a user receives a message from another user on the site).

If you have any experiences with email outsourcing then I would really appreciate if you shared your experience. Do you have a good experience with a company that you would like to recommend?

Answer (score 5):

Gmail is one of the best providers, it is easy to move your domain to their service and it is more or less spam free and the shiny web interface also really nice. you can delegate certain domains to users and they are able to manage that after that.

I would go for that.

http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/business/gmail.html

Comment: Worth mentioning that the Google Apps Standard Edition comes for free - 300 users, 7G mailboxes , imap/pop3 etc.  I use it for my personal/family e-mails for more than an year and it's great.

Comment: I use and love Google Apps for some purposes, but for this purpose there are some things to watch out for. There are limits on sending (for instance, a single account can't send to more than 500 different recipients any given day). They may also treat a large number of bounced outbound messages (bad signups, expired email addresses) as an indicator (one amongst many) that you're spamming.  I wouldn't expect any support for free accounts.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: how many folks send mail to more than 500 different recipients in one day?

Comment: @warren: There would be a problem if his site had more than 500 people sign up in one day or if the users got busy messages each other.

Answer (score 1):

My employer uses [Rackspace](http://rackspace.com), and loves it.

Comment: When valid, I don't mind down-votes, but this is a valid option. Why the downvote?

Comment: My company also uses Rackspace Email and is very happy with them. Reliable, full-featured, good price, and good support.